# Core Audio (iOS 5.1) Reverb2 properties do not exist, error code -10877

Tags: ios, core-audio

I am playing with Apple's sample project "LoadPresetDemo". I have added the reverb audio unit `AudioUnit kAudioUnitSubType_Reverb2` to the graph, which is the only iOS reverb available. In the CoreAudio header file "AudioUnitParameters.h", it states that Reverb2 should respond to these parameters:

```
enum {
    // Global, CrossFade, 0->100, 100
    kReverb2Param_DryWetMix = 0,
    // Global, Decibels, -20->20, 0
    kReverb2Param_Gain = 1,
    // Global, Secs, 0.0001->1.0, 0.008
    kReverb2Param_MinDelayTime = 2,
    // Global, Secs, 0.0001->1.0, 0.050
    kReverb2Param_MaxDelayTime = 3,
    // Global, Secs, 0.001->20.0, 1.0
    kReverb2Param_DecayTimeAt0Hz = 4,
    // Global, Secs, 0.001->20.0, 0.5
    kReverb2Param_DecayTimeAtNyquist = 5,
    // Global, Integer, 1->1000
    kReverb2Param_RandomizeReflections = 6,
};
```

After the AUGraph has been initialized and started, everything compiles, I hear sound.

Next, I alter the kReverb2Param_DryWetMix parameter (changing to full wet mix):

```
AudioUnitSetParameter(_reverbUnit, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, kReverb2Param_DryWetMix, 100.0f, 0);
```

All good, I hear sound with full wet mixed reverb.

Now hear is where I run into issues. When trying to alter any parameter other than `kReverb2Param_DryWetMix` I get error code `-10877`. It seems as if these other parameters listed in the header file do not actually exist.

For example, calling

```
AudioUnitSetParameter(_reverbUnit, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, kReverb2Param_DecayTimeAtNyquist, 20.0f, 0)
```

Throws the `-10877` error.

Is this a bug? Have I omitted any audio frameworks? Have I not imported specific audio headers?

The current audio frameworks included are AVFoundation and AudioToolbox.
The current audio imports are

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>
```

I have scoured google with no solution. I know I have problems when the Google route fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I tested with simulator and iPhone 4S device, same problem.

**UPDATE:** I have tried

```
AudioUnitGetParameter(_reverbUnit, kReverb2Param_DecayTimeAtNyquist, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &value)
```

and it returns a value of `0.500000`, which means the property does exist. So what am I doing wrong in setting the value?

Comment: Have a look in AUComponent.h. Looks like -10877 is kAudioUnitErr_InvalidElement "The specified element is not valid". Googling the error constant throws up some results, e.g. http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2002/Sep/msg00470.html

Comment: Thanks for where to locate the error code, I was having a hard time finding which header had the codes. This helped me track down what I did wrong.

Comment: glad you got it. Don't forget to accept your answer! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doh! I realize that I was confusing `AudioUnitSetParameter` with `AudioUnitSetProperty`, including their parameters. Man, subtle but evil.

Comment: Hi,I am having the exact same issue. Do you mind posting an example of how you solved yours with AudioUnitSetProperty? Many thanks.

Comment: Assuming you initialized everything correctly.... AudioUnitSetParameter(_reverbUnitModule.unit, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, kReverb2Param_DryWetMix, 50.0, 0);////////    
    
AudioUnitSetParameter(_reverbUnitModule.unit, kReverb2Param_DecayTimeAt0Hz, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, 1, 0);