# Setting the parameters of a AudioUnit Reverb?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

I have a AudioUnit Reverb in a Audio Unit graph and it processes the audio data well (nice reverberated sound in the speakers). But I am having trouble settings the parameters of the effects. The only paraemter I can set is the DryWet setting. The other ones fails to be modified.

So the following works:

```
AudioUnitSetParameter(reverbUnit,kAudioUnitScope_Global,0,kReverb2Param_DryWetMix,50,0);
```

But not these ones:

```
AudioUnitSetParameter(reverbUnit,kAudioUnitScope_Global,0,kReverb2Param_DecayTimeAt0Hz,4.0,0);          AudioUnitSetParameter(reverbUnit,kAudioUnitScope_Global,0,kReverb2Param_DecayTimeAtNyquist,4.0,0);
AudioUnitSetParameter(reverbUnit,kAudioUnitScope_Global,0,kReverb2Param_Gain,3.0,0);
AudioUnitSetParameter(reverbUnit,kAudioUnitScope_Global,0,kReverbParam_FilterBandwidth,3.0,0);
AudioUnitSetParameter(reverbUnit,kAudioUnitScope_Global,0,kReverbParam_FilterGain,3.0f,0);
```

I have seen a post ([Core Audio (iOS 5.1) Reverb2 properties do not exist, error code -10877](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362709/core-audio-ios-5-1-reverb2-properties-do-not-exist-error-code-10877)) that refers to the same problem but could not work out a solution.

Any help? Many thanks.

André

Answer (score 7):

yes, this confused me at first. the second argument is the id of the parameter,3rd is scope. so:

```
AudioUnitSetParameter(reverbUnit,kReverb2Param_DecayTimeAt0Hz,kAudioUnitScope_Global,0,4.0,0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Another bizarre feature of Core audio. It now works well. Cool!